# Calculating future costs from renewing dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet that will keep track of current and future costs for items with a known shelf life. This includes what the product is, cost of the product, life of the product in months, and date of last purchase.

I've tried a few ways of fiddling around with Excel formulas to get this to work.

My Table looks like this:

```
| Product | Cost | Life(months) | Purchased |
|---------|------|--------------|-----------|
| SHOES   | 25   | 24           | 1-1-2019  |
| HAT     | 15   | 48           | 1-1-2019  |
| DYE     | 5    | 12           | 1-1-2019  |

| YEAR | TOTAL COST BY YEAR |
|------|--------------------|
| 2019 |                    |
| 2020 |                    |
| 2021 |                    |
| 2022 |                    |
| 2023 |                    |
```

My current formula looks like this, though it is not functioning correctly(I always get 0):

```
=SUMIF($D$2:$D$4, MOD(A7-YEAR($D$2:$D$4),($C$2:$C$4/12))= 0, $B$2:$B$4)
```

Essentially what I am trying to say is:

If the future year I am checking for is one I will have to replace that item in, add in the cost for that item to that years total.

so in 2019, since I just purchased all of the items, I should have a total cost of $45.
2020 = $5 because I only need to replace the dye. 
2021 = $30 because I need to replace the shoes and dye.

etc

the items need to be continually replaced.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Why you not calculating years? Much easier, if you but on 1-1-2019, 1 year later instead of 12 months you get to replace dye....Or are the products on your shelf not exactly multiples of 12 months? The way you described it now, they actually are.

Comment: They are not always going to be in full years. The current items in inventory are but I wanted to leave it in months in the event that it is something that is replaced every 1.5 years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the combination of formulas SUM() and IF() as an ARRAY Formula.

If the data is located like that in the spreadsheet:

[image]

The formula for cell **C6** is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROUNDUP(ROUNDDOWN((DATE(B6,1,1)+365-$E$2:$E$4)/365*12,0)/$D$2:$D$4,0)-ROUNDUP(ROUNDDOWN((DATE(B6,1,1)-$E$2:$E$4)/365*12,0)/$D$2:$D$4,0),$C$2:$C$4)
```

Make sure to press CRTL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of ENTER to confirm the formula so you get the brackets on the formula like that:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(ROUNDUP(ROUNDDOWN((DATE(B6,1,1)+365-$E$2:$E$4)/365*12,0)/$D$2:$D$4,0)-ROUNDUP(ROUNDDOWN((DATE(B6,1,1)-$E$2:$E$4)/365*12,0)/$D$2:$D$4,0),$C$2:$C$4)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a somewhat 'secret' function called `DATEDIF`.

[image]

Formula in `B8`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((INT(DATEDIF($D$2,DATE(A8,1,1),"m")/$C$2:$C$4)=DATEDIF($D$2,DATE(A8,1,1),"m")/$C$2:$C$4)*$B$2:$B$4)
```

> *"The DATEDIF (Date + Dif) function is a "compatibility" function that comes from Lotus 1-2-3. For reasons unknown, it is only documented in Excel 2000, but it works in all Excel versions since that time. As Chip Pearson says: DATEDIF is treated as the drunk cousin of the Formula family. Excel knows it lives a happy and useful life, but will not speak of it in polite conversation."([Exceljet](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-datedif-function))*

Comment: This works great, thank you. I noticed, however, doing the calculation with the purchase date being later in the year (say I purchased today) the calculation was thrown off due to the subtraction in the second portion. I fixed this with a simple if statement where I didn't do the subtraction part if the result of said subtraction was negative.

Comment: @poprocks, glad this helped you. Please accept the answer to mark it as answered. See the help section on this website if you don't know how.